# Why does 身体 mean both "body" and "health"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've seen a curious Chinese word 身体. At first, I have discovered that it means 'body' and is a word with a broader meaning in comparison to 身材 or 体格. But I never understood why it means 'body' or, yet another meaning, 'health'. There is a question 《 你身体好吗？》which literally means '**How is your health?**'. While trying to seek for etymology, I turned out to be stuck because searching engines gave me no proper result about it.

Thanks for any help in finding the answer.

Comment: The concepts of one's body and one's health seem very closely related to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

身体 doesn't mean health, it just means 'body'.

你**身体**好吗？ (is your **body** fine) =  how is your **body**.

If your body is fine (身体很好), then you are healthy

If your body is not fine (身体不好), then you are not healthy

We have a word for health and it is 健康

> How is your **health** = 你的**健康**如何？

> Are you **healthy**? = 你**健康**吗?

> Is your **body healthy**? = 你的**身体健康**吗?

体格 means 'physique' (the form, size, and development of a person's body) = The condition of one's body, e.g. 体格強建， 体格孱弱 (Strong physique, weak physique)

体格不佳， (one's physique is not great) doesn't mean 身体不好 (one's body is not fine/ not healthy), it just means one's physique is weak e.g. too short, too thin, lack strength, and so on

Edit:

身体健康 (the body's health) doesn't include mental health, which is called 精神健康.

For the health of both body and mind, it is 身心健康 (the health of the mind and body)

*Since 健康 can be an adjective or noun 身体健康 can mean 'the body's health' or 'one's body is healthy'*

Comment: "If your body is fine (身体很好), then you are healthy". This doesn't include mental health, does it?

Comment: See my edit at  the bottom